# Bytearray conversion, integer is required error on python3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

asking for an integer on 0x00 hex position, python3

```
>>> command = bytearray()
>>> command.extend(chr(0x00))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Comment: What is your question?  Please see [ask] and how to post a [mcve].

Comment: You're trying to extend a bytearray with a (unicode) string. You'll need a list of bytes. Or simply use `command.append(0x00)`.

Comment: @9769953 Not quite. They'll need a list (or any iterable, really) of *ints*.

Comment: Why are you using `extend` to add a single element to the array? What were you trying to do here? What's the output you expected to have after this `extend` operation?

Comment: @Aran-Fey except that the integers need to be in the range 0 -- 256. Hence my choice of the word "bytes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bytearrays consist of either `bytes` (`b'\x00'`) or byte-sized `int`s (`0x00`). The result of `chr(0x00)` is a unicode string, however.

You can feed `bytearray.extend` with either a) a bytes string or b) an iterable of byte-sized integers. Both of these represent "sequence of bytes", which a `bytearray` is. Also, both can be used with hex notation.

```
command.extend(b'\x00')
command.extend([0x00])
```

In case you want to add a single integer, you can also use `bytearray.append`:

```
command.append(0x00)
```

---

Since a string is an iterable, `bytearray.extend` tries to append its elements. These are also strings, however. Hence, the error that an integer was expected.